# Is there a way to declare a vector of enums types inside a module?

Tags: rust, module, enums, constants, static-variables

I wish to add a static variable to a module so that I can access the variable by doing `module_name::variable_name`. However, I want this variable to be a vector of enum types.

Here is what I mean:

```
pub mod cards{
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum SUIT{
        CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE,
    }
    
    pub const all_cards: Vec<SUIT> = vec![SUIT::CLUB, SUIT::DIAMOND, SUIT::HEART, SUIT::SPADE];
}

fn main(){
    println!("{:?}", cards::all_cards);
}
```

But doing the above gives me two errors:

```
error[E0010]: allocations are not allowed in constants
```

and

```
error[E0015]: cannot call non-const fn `slice::<impl [SUIT]>::into_vec::<std::alloc::Global>` in constants
```

Is there a way to declare a vector of enums types inside a module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example you can instead use an Array because of fixed size of `ALL_CARDS`. [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=44743967178402b80b1c53efa9f0d4c9)

```
use crate::cards::ALL_CARDS;

pub mod cards {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub enum SUIT {
        CLUB,
        DIAMOND,
        HEART,
        SPADE,
    }

    pub const ALL_CARDS: [SUIT; 4] = [SUIT::CLUB, SUIT::DIAMOND, SUIT::HEART, SUIT::SPADE];
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", ALL_CARDS);
}
```

Vector requires a heap allocation and as error message says "allocation are not allowed in constants".  So when you need a global static data which needs to be initialized on heap once during lifetime of a program: have a look at  https://crates.io/crates/once_cell or https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static

Note I'm using uppercase for constant value as per [Rust naming convention](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/naming.html)

Answer (score 1):

Why not declare it as an [`array`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) instead?

```
pub mod cards{
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
    pub enum SUIT{
        CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE,
    }
    
    pub const all_cards: [SUIT; 4] = [SUIT::CLUB, SUIT::DIAMOND, SUIT::HEART, SUIT::SPADE];
}

fn main(){
    println!("{:?}", cards::all_cards); // [CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE]
}
```